# keeping screen static when click link

Tags: jquery, static, click, anchor

Hi I was wondering if anyone know how to keep the screen in a static position with jquery  when a link which has a "#" href is clicked?

Regards,

Phil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // OR:
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
return false;
```

Comment: Thx both, had to give the tick to the first post